# Using CA inside the host

Tags: ssh, certificate, openssh

I have gone through [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu).

I have a question if I can have my CA instance on my host server itself. This is because I have only one server and 5 clients accessing it. I want the certificate based authentication but cannot afford to have another CA server for this.

The link talks about having CA server to sign certificates. **Can I have CA on my server itself and sign all the public keys from there and save it on my host server?**

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to keep the CA in a separate host is security.

If you have only one server, someone breaking into it will only have access to that one server, no matter what. But if you had 10 servers and kept the CA private key on one of them, then someone who had broken into that server could sign themselves a key for accessing *all* of your servers.

For personal use, it doesn't matter much. If you are the only admin of that server, you could keep the keys on a USB stick, or even rely just on the key's own passphrase – it's up to you to decide how risky that is.